# OCR - Recognizing pricetags with iphone (openCV/Tesseract/Other methods?)

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv, ocr, tesseract

This question has been asked before, but each solution seems to be custom tailored to its purpose, so I wonder if any of you that understand OCR can help me find my fit.

I wish to recognize price-tags with the iPhone camera.
I've tried using tesseract with "digit only" mode (without any modifications/training) , but it fails miserably 99% of the time.

So, what would be a good fit here? Training tesseract with lots of images of price-tags/fonts?

Perhaps using openCV and training it with thousands of images?

Maybe you know of another engine that can do it?

There are so many directions to go with this one, I don't know where to start...

**(edit : I am looking for an open-source solution. Not a remote service..**)

Thanks, Roey.

Comment: they are many sdks available in market one of them is abby try may be that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that training will not be your solution, as it translates the input into a histogram and has nothing to do with actual text recognition. I think openCV does however have some OCR specific methods and I'm sure it has an iOS-compatible framework [here](http://code.google.com/p/opencv-ios/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with GPUImage open source library with tesseract. The link for GPUImage library is https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage . why can't you try some image processing libraries like https://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are other engines that can do that, even free. Look here: [RTRSDK.com](http://rtrsdk.com).

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY

Comment: is ios sdk of ABBYY  free?

Comment: There are both free and extended licenses. Please refer to licensing page on the web site https://rtrsdk.com/licensing/